# Symfony adds % symbols to my variables in place of square brackets

Tags: variables, symfony, text, twig

I am currently experiencing a weird problem. I am creating a variable from the url from the current page.

```
{% set var = app.request.url %}
```

And this works on another page. The generated url is also OK;

```
site/banana[is_yellow].
```

Unfortunately, my url comes out as `Banana%20%5Bis_yellow:54%5D` (when I print the variable). I need the variable to remain `Banana[is_yellow]`

Thus, my question is how do I get Symfony (or Twig?) to not replace the square brackets with random symbols and numbers?

Comment: how do you print the variable can you include the code?

Comment: {{ var | raw }}, and to create this variable {% set var = app.request.url %}

Comment: you set the variable to app.request.url and print it afterwards using {{ var|raw }} and your template shows `Banana%20%5Bis_yellow:54%5D` ? you are stating random strings .. does the output change or is it always `Banana%20%5Bis_yellow:54%5D` ?

Comment: I just checked, and it remains Banana%20%5Bis_yellow:54%5D

Comment: What I am noticing is; space = %20, [ = %5B and ] = %5D

Comment: Noticing this, I just made a filter to do a preg replace for those characters. It works, but I would rather not have all that code ... hoping for a better idea/alternative if you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the url comes already escaped from the browsers request. Twig doesn't come with a url_decode filter to match its [url_encode one](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html), so you'll need to write it.

in **src/Your/Bundle/Twig/Extension/YourExtension.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Twig\Extension;

class YourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFilters()
  {
    return array(
        'url_decode' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'urlDecode')
    );
  }

  /**
   * URL Decode a string
   *
   * @param string $url
   *
   * @return string The decoded URL
   */
  public function urlDecode( $url )
  {
    return urldecode( $url );
  }

  /**
   * Returns the name of the extension.
   *
   * @return string The extension name
   */
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'your_extension';
  }
}
```

And then add it to your services configuration in **app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    your.twig.extension:
        class: Your\Bundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

And then use it!

```
{{ var|url_decode }}
```